# What to include from permissive licensed Open Source library?

Tags: open-source, mit-license, bsd-license, apache-license

I'm writing a library and toolset for the manipulation of a software's data files.

The library and toolset are written in Python.

As I build the library, I start to rely on 3rd party libraries that needs to be installed separately. However, the end-user of the toolset might not have the expertise needed to install those 3rd party libraries. So, I decided to include those 3rd party libraries in my repository for these kinds of users.

(In the `setup.py` script, I export *only* my library and toolset, and explicitly specify dependencies to those 3rd party libraries. My project's README file already contains proper linkage and attribution to all 3rd party libraries I use.)

These 3rd party libraries are released under permissive licenses, namely Apache License 2.0, MIT License, and 2-Clause BSD License.

Now, besides the required (by me) library files and required (by the license) accompaniment files (e.g., NOTICE, LICENSE, etc.), must I also include files that I do not use, for instance: those libraries' setup.py, .hgignore/.gitignore, nosetests, examples, etc.?